# Problems whit import boto3 in a virtual env

Tags: boto3, boto

I'm trying to import boto3 modeule in a virtual environemnt.

import os
import boto3

Although I'm having the following problem with import command:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <module>
      1 import os
      2 import botocore
----> 3 import boto3

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py:16, in <module>
      1 # Copyright 2014 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
      2 #
      3 # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"). You
   (...)
     11 # ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
     12 # language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
     14 import logging
---> 16 from boto3.compat import _warn_deprecated_python
     17 from boto3.session import Session
     19 __author__ = 'Amazon Web Services'

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/compat.py:20, in <module>
     17 import warnings
     19 from botocore.vendored import six
---> 20 from boto3.exceptions import PythonDeprecationWarning
     22 if six.PY3:
     23     # In python3, socket.error is OSError, which is too general
     24     # for what we want (i.e FileNotFoundError is a subclass of OSError).
     25     # In py3 all the socket related errors are in a newly created
     26     # ConnectionError
     27     SOCKET_ERROR = ConnectionError

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/exceptions.py:39, in <module>
     30     pass
     33 # We're subclassing from botocore.exceptions.DataNotFoundError
     34 # to keep backwards compatibility with anyone that was catching
     35 # this low level Botocore error before this exception was
     36 # introduced in boto3.
     37 # Same thing for ResourceNotExistsError below.
     38 class UnknownAPIVersionError(
---> 39     Boto3Error, botocore.exceptions.DataNotFoundError
     40 ):
     41     def __init__(self, service_name, bad_api_version, available_api_versions):
     42         msg = (
     43             f"The '{service_name}' resource does not an API version of: {bad_api_version}\n"
     44             f"Valid API versions are: {available_api_versions}"
     45         )

AttributeError: module 'botocore.exceptions' has no attribute 'DataNotFoundError'
```

Someone knows how to fix it, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is boto3 installed in your virtual environment? Check with pip list

Comment: @paisanco yes, it is (some of the packages installed below).


big@abd-virtual-machine:/mnt/hgfs/PBD$ pip list
Package                Version             
---------------------- --------------------                                    
boto3                  1.21.27             
botocore               1.24.27

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple dockerfile with python3.8 botocore and boto3.

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN pip install botocore boto3
COPY hello.py .

ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "hello.py" ]
```

When running pip list I see:

```
Package         Version
--------------- -------
boto3           1.21.27
botocore        1.24.27
jmespath        1.0.0
pip             22.0.4
python-dateutil 2.8.2
s3transfer      0.5.2
setuptools      57.5.0
six             1.16.0
urllib3         1.26.9
wheel           0.37.1
```

Using a test file I can have

```
import boto3
import botocore

print("Hello world")
```

and the file executes without the error you've run into.

My suspicion is either you've got incompatible versions pinned or there's another dependency requesting an older version of botocore and causing the error you see. Maybe upgrading all the dependencies to newer versions could help?

Answer (score 0):

I copied the contents of the folders related to boto3 to the virtual machine and it is working. Some files were not being created for some reason.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).